# Stacking Transparent GIF with Pillow Errors [Fixed!]

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a simple application that fetches radar images from NOAA, then stacks them to make an image for display. I've never used the PILLOW library before, but I do have some experience with Python.

The images are GIF files and have transparent parts. You can see example images at the urls in my code below. I've got a white background and an overlay made from stacking several of the overlays on their site as a single transparent image on my computer.

Here is my current code:

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Warnings/Short/EWX_Warnings_0.gif', 'warnings_now.gif')
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/EWX_N0R_0.gif', 'radar_now.gif')
radar = Image.open('radar_now.gif')
warnings = Image.open('warnings_now.gif')
background = Image.open('Background.gif')
overlay = Image.open('Overlay.gif')
background.paste(radar, (0,0), radar)
background.paste(overlay, (0,0), overlay)
background.paste(warnings, (0,0), warnings)
background.save('radar_final.gif', 'GIF')
```

I've read in a lot of places, both here and on other sites that to properly stack transparent images, you need to do `image_name.paste(transparent_image, (0,0), transparent_image)` and that by using a third parameter, PIL will interpret the alpha channel of transparent_image as a mask. However, whenever I run this, I get the following error instead of getting an image as output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "radar2.py", line 9, in <module>
background.paste(radar, (0,0), radar)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1314, in paste
self.im.paste(im, box, mask.im)
ValueError: bad transparency mask
```

I've searched all over for a solution, and I've only come across a solutions for a similar error happening with PNG images, where they were converted to RGBA mode. When I tried this with my images, I got an identical error (except for line numbers). I wasn't expecting this to work as I've read that GIF images are only P or L mode.

These are all P mode images, and they all have one alpha layer. I also tried splitting off the alpha layer to use as a mask, but that also resulted in a  `ValueError: bad transparency mask`.

I can't seem to find much about transparent GIF images and Pillow. There is this one thing that keeps popping up about converting to PNG, but the solutions in that don't seem relevant.

Thanks for any help!

Note: This is on a 64-bit Gentoo Linux system running Python 3.3 and whatever is the most recent version of Pillow in the Gentoo repos.

Comment: It's not clear if you've already tried this, but I would first convert all the gif images to RGBA format in memory before pasting everything together. Color gifs are usually paletted, and merging ("stacking") them in that format is problematic, if not impossible.

Comment: @martineau: I did try that but ended up with the same error. If you look at the images, they've got two layers: one alpha and one with everything else. I'm not sure how to deal with this.

Comment: Thank you martineau. I don't know why that wasn't working the first time. It works great now!

Comment: Perhaps you're using a new version of Pillow. I just checked and the latest version is 2.8.2.